# Regex to remove digits & hyphen(-) from end of a string

Tags: c#, regex

How to remove digits & "-" from end of a string using regex in C#.

```
 string name= "100% program name - 200";              

 Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[0-9]+$");
 name= rgx.Replace(name, "").Replace(" -","");
```

Currently it return "**100% program name**", but I need to do it using a single regex expression without using second replace  `Replace(" -","")`

Comment: Do you mean like this? `[0-9& -]+$` https://regex101.com/r/lo5V3t/1 Or should it be that exact pattern like `\s-\s\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/lo5V3t/2

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think OP don't want to replace `&` just used it as a short hand for "and". But yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: how variable is your input? is this: `"100% program name - 200 -100"` possible?

Comment: @Magnetron Ah I see, in that case the `&` can be omitted from the character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepend the string of the second replacement and add a space after it to the regex and use a single replacement.

`- [0-9]+$`

.NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=+-+%5b0-9%5d%2b%24&i=100%25+program+name+-+200)

```
string name= "100% program name - 200";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@" - [0-9]+$");
name= rgx.Replace(name, "");
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Result

> 100% program name